# chrome : your connection to site not secure

Tags: windows-7, google-chrome, security, certificate, window

Recently, I encountered an error in `chrome` that the site is not secure and `security certificate` is not valid.
then i found answer  [here](https://superuser.com/a/1679138/1560649). it solved this error which was occurring on every site but since I updated my certificate now chrome working fines but now the problem is this error still persist on some site even if I have updated the certificate.

[image]

`Chrome version: 95`

Comment: Not certain if this is the issue, but Chrome 93 and and(I believe) the latest versions of Firefox will generate this warning due to [HSTS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_Strict_Transport_Security) enforcement. You may want to try the same sites with older browsers (e.g. Chrome 92 or earlier or an earlier version of Firefox) and see if the issue resolves itself.

Comment: that is not an error ... it is a warning

Comment: Be sure your time is set correctly.