# How to fix SSL issue from 30-September-2021

Tags: windows-10, https, ssl-certificate, letsencrypt

After having this SSL error, I have search and know that it start from 30/09/2021, cause from let's encrypt.

I tried updating my windows, updating chrome, manually downloaded and added some certificate file `CER.pfx, CERTI.pfx, CERTIFI.pfx, FINISH.cer, FIXE FINISH Update 2021.10.02.cer` and could go to some site like store.steampowered.com... but I just cannot go to stackoverflow (see image below).

How could I fix this problem?

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Update your operating system and/or install the appropriate Let’s Encrypt Root CA.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [DST Root CA X3 expiration on Windows7. Which update I need to install? Are there workarounds?](https://superuser.com/questions/1679135/dst-root-ca-x3-expiration-on-windows7-which-update-i-need-to-install-are-there). The answer submitted to that question will explain and resolve your issue with websites that use Lets Encrpt SSL certificates

Comment: So did you install the new Root Let’s Encrypt CA?

Comment: @Ramhound Thank you, I'll try after going home tonight.

Comment: @Ramhound I do install the `isrgrootx1.der` as in the refer link, restart chrome and boom,  it work like charm. Upvoted OP and answer post, and go thank you again!