# Chrome error, Invalid Stack Exchange Certificate

Tags: windows-7, certificate

Windows 7 Pro 64bit
Returned PC from sleep and got this error when loading any Stack exchange site. So far no other site does this.

Says clock on my PC is wrong but its not. Certificate date looks good but says its invalid

Any Suggestions to fix the issue?

Thanks for looking.

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [NET::ERR\_CERT\_DATE\_INVALID and certificate is not expired](https://superuser.com/questions/1679010/neterr-cert-date-invalid-and-certificate-is-not-expired).  The Stack Exchange servers are properly configured to provide the complete and valid certificate chain, your Windows 7 installation, does not trust the correct root CA certificate.

Comment: [Support for urgent Trusted Root updates for Windows Root Certificate Program in Windows](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/support-for-urgent-trusted-root-updates-for-windows-root-certificate-program-in-windows-a4ac4d6c-7c62-3b6e-dfd2-377982bf3ea5)[.](https://superuser.com/questions/1679135/dst-root-ca-x3-expiration-on-windows7-which-update-i-need-to-install-are-there?noredirect=1&lq=1)

Comment: You should post the edit as an answer not part of the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue is caused by incorrect time, in my case time was almost correct except it was set to AM when it needed to be PM.

Still no clue how the time was set 12 hours off, but did notice a time server update close to when the problem started.

Also saw [this article](https://www.darkreading.com/risk/companies-face-issues-as-let-s-encrypt-root-certificate-expires) on Oct 1, but don't think it was my issue.