# Chrome giving error https://superuser.com/ not secure

Tags: windows, windows-7, windows-10, google-chrome, security

wherever I try to access https://superuser.com/ chrome gives me an error that

Your connection is not private.
Attackers might be trying to steal your information from superuser.com (for example, passwords, messages, or credit cards). Learn more

```
NET::ERR_CERT_DATE_INVALID
```

To get Chrome’s highest level of security, turn on enhanced protection
This server could not prove that it is `superuser.com;` its security certificate is not valid at this time. This may be caused by a misconfiguration or an attacker intercepting your connection.

*My system info*

> I am using windows 7

> chrome version 94.0.4606.71 (Official Build) (64-bit)

> I don't have any security software or antivirus installed

> This error only shown on some websites like superuser,quora etc

*what I have tried*

> Reinstalling

> clear data

**On firefox there is no issue**

Comment: This is very wrong. What are your versions of Windows and Chrome? Does it happen with other browsers than Chrome? Do you have installed any security software beside Windows Defender?

Comment: Does https://superuser.com/questions/1679135/dst-root-ca-x3-expiration-on-windows7-which-update-i-need-to-install-are-there/1679138#1679138 answer the question?

Comment: @harrymc I am using windows 7 and chrome Version 94.0.4606.71 (Official Build) (64-bit). No, I do not have any security software installed.

Comment: Does is happen with IE or Firefox?

Comment: no, on firefox no issue

Comment: I don't know what went wrong with Chrome, but I suggest to save bookmarks, uninstall it, clean out all its folders and reinstall the latest version.

Comment: Check you clock>>>>>https://superuser.com/questions/1679807/chrome-error-invalid-stack-exchange-certificate?

Comment: This was also covered on the main SE Meta - https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/370443/invalid-certificate-on-all-se-sites - Let's Encrypt's certificate has expired & you are on an unsupported OS so you don't automatically get a new version.

Comment: @user1686 yes your answer solved my issue with chrome. i was struggling to solve it for 1 month . thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

I use Windows 7 and I had the same problem, same error irrespective of browser. I  found it was because I'd disabled the Windows Update service not knowing that by doing so I was preventing a root certificate from being downloaded and installed. I set the Update Service startup type to Automatic, started the service, waited for a few hours then checked and the problem had gone.