# How to manually update windows certificates store?

Tags: trusted-root-certificates

I wanted to connect uTorrent to this tracker : desitorrents.tv , but it seems there is a problem with verifying the website certificate when uTorrent tries to connect to that website ( i guess uTorrent relies on Windows stored certificates). According to Firefox that website is using a certificate verified by "Let's Encrypt". When i opened "certmgr" on windows (W7 SP1 32 bit) i found a certificate issued by "DST Root CA X3" to "Let's Encrypt Authority X3" (Under: Intermediate Certification Authorities > Certificates). The certificate expired on 17/03/2021. So what i must do to have a valid certificate on my machine that can fix the problem ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [NET::ERR\_CERT\_DATE\_INVALID and certificate is not expired](https://superuser.com/questions/1679010/neterr-cert-date-invalid-and-certificate-is-not-expired).  [Here](https://superuser.com/questions/1679135/dst-root-ca-x3-expiration-on-windows7-which-update-i-need-to-install-are-there?rq=1) is an additional duplicate to this question.  However, the best way to solve your problem is to upgrade to a supported version of Windows. In the answer to the duplicate question I linked to the certificate you need to install (ISRG Root X1).

Comment: I installed  the root certificate: "ISRG Root X1 Cross-signed by DST Root CA X3" on "Trusted Root Certification Authorities",  then the intermediate certificate: "Let’s Encrypt R3 Signed by ISRG Root X1" on "Intermediate Certification Authorities" . I hope that was correct , but for now i still have the issue, maybe i should delete the outdated certificate ? or i just need to reboot the computer?

Comment: You shouldn't make a habit of removing root CA certificates. The certificate is expired so all modern browsers will flag the situation. It's necessary to remove the expired certificate. It's unclear why you installed X3 when it was already installed.  `ISRG Root X1` is the current Let's Encrypt root CA certificate.

Comment: Because "Let's Encrypt Authority X3" located inside "Intermediate Certification Authorities" expired on 17/03/2021, so i thought that i need both the new root certificate and the itermediate one.

Comment: You already had X3 installed per your question. It really doesn't matter, the only certificate you needed was `ISRG Root X1` per the duplicate's answer.

Comment: Ok so the root certificate is enough. Thanks @Ramhound