# aria2c fails: certificate expired

Tags: ssl, certificate

I used aria2 for many years to download, but now it ends with this error:

```
2022-07-28 17:36:05.765460 [ERROR] [AbstractCommand.cc:351] CUID#7 - Download aborted. URI=http://www.reversebeacon.net/raw_data/dl.php?f=20220726
Exception: [AbstractCommand.cc:351] errorCode=1 URI=https://www.reversebeacon.net/raw_data/dl.php?f=20220726
  -> [SocketCore.cc:1021] errorCode=1 SSL/TLS handshake failure: Error: Das empfangene Zertifikat ist abgelaufen.
(80090328)
```

The German error text says "certificate expired", but certificate at the reversebeacon.net webpage is not expired (September 2022), looked up with FF.

I use latest aria2c Version 1.36 in a W7 32bit VM.

Any idea?

Comment: There are more certificates involved than just the server's – see https://superuser.com/a/1679146 and https://superuser.com/q/1679135 for more.

Comment: You can simply add the ` --check-certificate=false` option as a workaround. Apart from that, **DO NOT continue to use Windows 7, it is EOL for over 2 1/2 years now and won't get any security updates**

Comment: Where should I add --check-certificate=false ?

Comment: Looking at the cert - its a letsencrypt certificate -and they switched root certificates around that time https://letsencrypt.org/docs/dst-root-ca-x3-expiration-september-2021/ . Depending on what certs aria2c uses - and the windows instance has available this *might* be the reason.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using aria2.conf, put check-certificate=false in it.

If not, you can start aria2c with --check-certificate=false.

Get more information here: https://aria2.github.io/manual/en/html/aria2c.html