# Two issues both related to certificates on Win 7

Tags: windows-7, google-chrome, certificate, zoom-meeting

I have two issues both related to certificates and perhaps both have common reason(s) I need to find out.

The first and less important issue is when I try to open any website via https in Chrome browser v103, I receive the error `NET::ERR_CERT_DATE_INVALID`. However, date and time on my laptop are set correctly.

The second and more important issue is when I try to install Zoom app for meetings v5.11.1 or the latest version 5.11.4, I receive the error `10003` and their support team said that the error is caused by certificates. They recommended to follow the instructions to install their certificate as described by the link https://support.zoom.us/hc/en-us/articles/6621090983949-Zoom-error-code-10003 and I followed them, but I still receive the error 10003 when trying to install the app.

So what and where I can see or check to resolve at least the second issue? Maybe some log files? Or certificate store? Any suggestions are welcome

I still use Windows 7 Home Premium. Please don't write just to upgrade it to Win 10 - I need a solution for the current version of Win

Comment: See https://superuser.com/a/1679146/1686 and https://superuser.com/q/1679135/1686.

Answer (score 2):

The error NET::ERR_CERT_DATE_INVALID relates to the last date of validity
of the certificate, not the date and time on your laptop.

The certificate seems to have elapsed, or it was created wrongly to
start with.